# @XmlTransient for a javaBean property

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling

I am interested in not marshaling/unmarshaling the principal field of my A object. I have added `XmlTransient` in different places but it still seem to marshal it.

Any ideas?

Here is class A:

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "A")
    public class AImpl implements A, Serializable {

    private String attrName;
    private String attrValue;

    @XmlTransient
    private Object principal;

    public class Adapter extends XmlAdapter<AImpl,A> {
        public A unmarshal(AImpl v) { return v; }
        public AImpl marshal(A v) { return (AImpl)v; }
    }

    public String getAttrName() {
    return attrName;
    }
    public void setAttrName(String s) {
    this.attrName = s;
    }

    public String getAttrValue() {
    return attrValue;
    }

    public void setAttrValue(String s) {
    this.attrValue = s;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Object getPrincipal() {
    return principal;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public void setPrincipal(Object o) {
    this.principal = o;
    }
}
```

Here is how I marshal it:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(AImpl.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT,true);
m.marshal(al sw);)
```

Comment: Regarding Bozho's answer, this link might help you understand why you should specify an @XmlAccessType http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying `@XmlAccessType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your class

Comment: @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)